# What's the correct method for CoreAudio realtime thread to communicate with UI thread?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-audio

I need to pass data between CoreAudio's realtime thread and the UI thread (one way, RT->UI). I know I can't use any Cocoa/Objective C methods like `performSelectorOnMainThread` or `NSNotification` and I can't use anything that will allocate memory as this will potentially block the RT thread.

What is the correct method for communicating between threads? Can I use GCD message queues or is there a more basic system to use?

Edit:

Thinking about this a bit more, I suppose I could use a lock free ring buffer, which the RT thread puts a message into, and the UI thread checks for messages to pull out. Is this the best way and if so is there a system already to do this in CoreAudio or available elsewhere or do I need to code it up myself?

Comment: I use ring buffers, with atomic C data types for the flags, and declare them volatile.  A frame rate or slower timer polls them on the UI end.  It's roll your own code.

Comment: Thank you. Doing some more research I found http://www.rossbencina.com/code/real-time-audio-programming-101-time-waits-for-nothing where Ross Bencina suggests using the Portaudio queue as a starting point so I'll look into doing this. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was a lot simpler than I expected and the solution I came up with was just to use the Portaudio ring buffer. I needed to add pa_ringbuffer.[ch] and pa_memorybarrier.h to my project and then define a MessageData structure to store in the ring buffer.

```
typedef struct MessageData {
    MessageType type;
    union {
        struct {
            NSUInteger position;
        } position;
    } data;
} MessageData;
```

Then I allocated some space to store 32 messages and created the ring buffer.

```
_playbackData->RTToMainBuffer = malloc(sizeof(MessageData) * 32);
PaUtil_InitializeRingBuffer(&_playbackData->RTToMainRB, sizeof(MessageData),
                            32, _playbackData->RTToMainBuffer);
```

Finally I started an NSTimer for every 20ms to pull data from the ring buffer

```
while (PaUtil_GetRingBufferReadAvailable(&_playbackData->RTToMainRB)) {
    MessageData *dataPtr1, *dataPtr2;
    ring_buffer_size_t sizePtr1, sizePtr2;

    // Should we read more than one at a time?
    if (PaUtil_GetRingBufferReadRegions(&_playbackData->RTToMainRB, 1,
                                        (void *)&dataPtr1, &sizePtr1,
                                        (void *)&dataPtr2, &sizePtr2) != 1) {
        continue;
    }

    // Parse message
    switch (dataPtr1->type) {
        case MessageTypeEOS:
            break;

        case MessageTypePosition:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
    PaUtil_AdvanceRingBufferReadIndex(&_playbackData->RTToMainRB, 1);
}
```

Then in the realtime thread, pushing a message to the ringbuffer was simply

```
MessageData *dataPtr1, *dataPtr2;
ring_buffer_size_t sizePtr1, sizePtr2;

if (PaUtil_GetRingBufferWriteRegions(&data->RTToMainRB, 1,
                                     (void *)&dataPtr1, &sizePtr1,
                                     (void *)&dataPtr2, &sizePtr2)) {
    dataPtr1->type = MessageTypePosition;
    dataPtr1->data.position.position = currentPosition;

    PaUtil_AdvanceRingBufferWriteIndex(&data->RTToMainRB, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A ringbuffer is a good solution. Two if you need to communicate both ways ie. inbox/outbox message passing.

This is a good implementation for iOS/Mac if you don't want to use Portaudio.

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPCircularBuffer